# WinJS Pivot Not Displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I have a Windows Phone app using HTML5 and Javascript.

I am using `WinJS.Utilities.empty();` to clear the DIV element and then `WinJS.UI.Pages.render();` to load pages in to the same DIV:

On one of the pages that is loaded in, I am trying to use a Pivot Control, I am using it declaritively like this:

```
<div id="MyAccountPivot" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Pivot" data-win-options="{title: 'MyAccount'}">
    <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem"
         data-win-options="{ header: 'current' }">

         <div id="current">

             Lorum Ipsum...

         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the page is loaded in, the Pivot control loads and renders, and the PivotItem headers render correctly. But when the content has been rendered, it is not visible. I have used the DOM explorer in Visual Studio to interrogate the markup and styling to find the issue. It appears that the container DIV elements for the PivotItem contents are out of place and are hidden behind the DIV that contains the PivotItem headers...

When I have tried using this markup in the parent page (rendered without using the `WinJS.UI.Pages.render();`) it works exactly as expected.

I have also tried creating the Pivot and its Items programmatically, but this produces the same results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you please a little javascript code of what you're doing?

Comment: @sebagomez Thanks for your reply and apologies for the delay. I haven't got anything else to show really, what I have entered in the question is essentially it.

Answer (score 0):

Getting me same issue while showing content without template, make some changes in css and it's works for me.
**HTML**

```
<div class="myPivot">
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Pivot">
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem" data-win-options="{ 'header': 'one' }">
-- item content---
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.myPivot {
}

.myPivot div.win-pivot-item {
    left:0px !important;
    visibility: visible;
    width:100%;    
}
.myPivot .win-pivot .win-pivot-surface {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```